# Control Access Request Dialog

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, access

I want to write in the text area that there in the control of access request programmatically 
I take copy of the control from sharePoint and added it in application page but I cann't catch it with code 
I think that there are way by Java script 
please, any help ??